# Maven compiler plugin issue with custom annotation processor

Tags: maven, annotations, maven-plugin, annotation-processing, immutables-library

I have written a custom annotation processor and configured with maven compiler plugin as shown below, I am facing issue with [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) annotation processor which is in my application class path. When I add my annotation processor via maven compiler plugin, the Immutables is giving compilation errors. I need Immutables as well in my project.

```html
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</generatedSourcesDirectory>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>
                org.smarttechie.TraceAnnotationProcessor
            </annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any hints to use Immutables/any annotation processors along with my custom annotation processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package your annotation processor into a JAR and include that JAR as a
compilation dependency.  Be sure to add
`META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` to your JAR
(contents single line with your processor class name):

```
org.smarttechie.TraceAnnotationProcessor
```

If you don't want your new JAR included as a dependency of your generated
artifact, mark it prodided and/or true.

Comment: Some how when  I add the jar which has the custom annotation processor, during the compile time the annotation processor is not invoked the way it was when I add it though maven plugin. The dependency scope is compile only.

Comment: My apologies, I neglected a step.  I have updated my answer.